# Where is the Java TextArea paint method implemented?

Tags: java, awt, textarea, paint

I am looking for the `paint` method implementation for a Java `TextArea` component ([java.awt.TextArea](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/AWT/java/awt/TextArea.java.htm)).

I have read through the source code for the class as well as its super class ([java.awt.TextComponent](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/AWT/java/awt/TextComponent.java.htm)), but have not found a `public void paint(Graphics g)` method implementation, which I think means the class would be using the default `Component#paint(Graphics)` implementation, which doesn't make sense. Am I missing something here? How is a `TextArea` component painted?

Comment: Since you've got the source code, why not have a look at the `Component#paint(Graphics)` method to see exactly how a `JTextArea` can be painted without defining its own `paint` method?

Comment: @Shakedown I did look at the [java.awt.Component](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/AWT/java/awt/Component.java.htm) source and the `paint` method is empty.

Comment: Whoops, I'm sorry, I meant `JComponent`, not `Component`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextArea is an AWT component, not a Swing component. It's thus what's called a heavyweight component, which means it's in fact implemented by a native component of the underlying platform/OS (i.e. a Windows/Gnome/Motif component, depending on the OS), called the peer of the component. The painting is thus done by the platform's native widget, and not by the component.

Comment: Ahh, so that's what the peer it references is. That makes sense. `JTextArea` and `JTextComponent` also do not contain a `paint` method. Are they also painted by the platform as well?

Comment: No. These are lightweight components. Read http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html for explanations.

Comment: IUUC, painting is delegated, e.g. [`javax.swing.plaf.TextUI`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/TextUI.html) for `JTextComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

`AWT Components` is dinosauruses from last milenium, and only by `back-compactible` are there and still exists, please/better would be to change that to the `Todays JComponents`, all starts with "J" here is list of [JComponents with tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html), but for Swing's JComponents is there `paintComponent(Graphics g)` instead of `paint(Graphics g)`

method paint is still there but for deepest painting in XxxXxxUI, for example [MetalButtonUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751311/creating-custom-button-in-java/5755124#5755124), but not for painting Image/Lines/Text ... and just try to avoid a [similar examples from year 2000](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/AntiAlias.htm) and another very old examples, that's really wrong implemntation for Custom Painting in Java6's Swing,

here is your required [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html) and [Java6 API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29)

on this Forum are plenty threads about `Painting Something in JComponents`

EDIT: if you want to paint something then look for [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) (is transparent by defalut), that best `JComponent` for  [2D Graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html), examples for that [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Catalog2D-Graphics-GUI.htm), and with paintComponent() method only

Comment: I understand `AWT Components` are outdated by the newer `Swing Components`. I'd be just as content being able to see `JTextArea`'s `paint` method (which is just as elusive). I'm looking to write my own `TextArea` class for use on the Amazon Kindle's Java 1.4.2 based KDK, as the KDK's implementation is somewhat broken. I want to use the Java API's implementation for a reference.