# MenuListener Implementation, how to detect which JMenu was clicked?

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenubar

If I have defined `JMenu` and `JMenuBar` like this:

```
private JMenuBar jMenuBar;
private JMenu jMenu1;

jMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
jMenu1 = new JMenu();
jMenu1.setText("ABOUT");

//and here add a MenuListener so that i can detect when a menu is clicked:
jMenu1.addMenuListener(this);

jMenuBar.add(jMenu1);
setJMenuBar(jMenuBar);


//and here i implement the menulisteners

public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
   //my logic here
}
public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {}
public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {}
```

Now it works fine. But the problem is if i have more then one menu, how can i distinguish between the two.
Like in the menu listener, how would i know the click came from menu1 or another menu 2?

I mean if i have another menu and i add menu listener for this menu as well:

```
jMenu2.addMenuListener(this);
```

then i can not distinguish from which menu the click came from. How can i do that?

Comment: using MenuListeners is unusual - which provokes the usual question: why do you think you need it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getSource()` method of [MenuEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/MenuEvent.html) class. Or you can also add separate listeners to both menus as anonymous class.

```
public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
   //Make sure jMenu1 and jMenu2 are accessible in here.
   if(e.getSource()==jMenu1)
      operationForMenu1();
   else if(e.getSource()==jMenu2)
      operationForMenu2();
}
```

or

```
   jMenu1.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {
        @Override
        public void menuSelected(MenuEvent arg0) {
            // operation here.
        }

        @Override
        public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    jMenu2.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {
        @Override
        public void menuSelected(MenuEvent arg0) {
            // operation here.
        }

        @Override
        public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
```

<del>If you choose second option then it will easy to use `ActionListener` instead of `MenuListener`. (Only if you do not want to do operation on menuCanceled and menuDeselected)</del> (removed this as suggested by @Kleopatra in comment)

Comment: -1 ActionListener is _not_ an alternative ... also see my comment to @GETah) +1 for getSource - in sum a zero :-)

Comment: @kleopatra: I suggested ActionListener, because I thought if he only want to do operation on click of menu then no need to add extra methods for that. Adding ActionListener with single method will do the job. That's why I also mentioned my answer that *(Only if you do not want to do operation on menuCanceled and menuDeselected)*. But may be I'm wrong in that as you are saying it's not good idea to add action listener in menu. Also `downvote + upvote = 8 rep.` ;p

Comment: well, the error is that a ActionListener registered on a JMenu does exactly ... nothing :-)

Comment: @kleopatra: Ok. Strike through that line. :)

Answer (score 2):

That is what [`getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) is for, which is a method `MenuEvent` inherits from `EventObject`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ActionListener` instead. Here is how you can capture a click on a menu item

```
 jMenu1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Perform action on menu1 clicked here
  }
 }
```

If you have more than one menu sharing the same bit of code when clicked then you can refactor the action listener into a separate class.

Comment: technically incorrect, the question is about a _JMenu_ not a _JMenuItem_ (refraining from down-voting for now as it probably will turn out that listening to actions indeed will be the real requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that one of ways is add `ButtonModel` to `JMenuItem` or add `JMenuItems` to the `ButtonGroup` can solve confortly that too, example for [ButtonModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751311/creating-custom-button-in-java/5755124#5755124)

Comment: no, a) there's rarely a need to touch a menu's model b) a ButtonGroup has nothing to do with any aspect of the question (will revert if it'll turn out you have the magic future looking eye :-)

Answer (score 0):

I came here to see if there was anything I preferred to getSource(), and decided to stick with getSource. It's my preference to work with strings (vs comparing objects), so I'm posting my code in case it's helpful to anyone. (I know some people don't like early returns, don't like switch statements, don't like K&R. Again, personal preference, adapt as desired.)

```
public void menuSelected(MenuEvent evt) {
    String menuName;
    Object obj = evt.getSource();
    if (obj instanceof JMenu) {
        JMenu menu = (JMenu) obj;
        menuName = menu.getText();
        System.out.println(menuName);
    } else {
        return;
    }
    switch (menuName) {
    case "Edit":
        if (undo.hasPreviousState()) {
            jMenuItemEditUndo.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            jMenuItemEditUndo.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if (undo.hasNextState()) {
            jMenuItemEditRedo.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            jMenuItemEditRedo.setEnabled(false);
        }
        break;
    case "Insert":
        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = (DefaultListModel<String>) jListTags.getModel();
        if (listModel.contains("table")) {
            jMenuItemInsertTable.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            jMenuItemInsertTable.setEnabled(false);
        }
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Menu " + menuName + " not a special case in menuSelected");
    }
}
```

Naturally, JMenu(s) that don't addMenuListener() don't even trigger menuSelected().

Answer (score -1):

Change the colour of the button or label. simple and short xoxo

> Block quote
>   Public static void main ()