# Do different action using the same event

Tags: java, events, mouselistener

I'm training with GUI in Java. I use **JMenuBar**

```
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
```

in this there is **JMenu**

```
JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
```

in the bar there are two **JMenuItem**

```
JMenuItem creditsItem = new JMenuItem("Credits");
JMenuItem preferenceItem = new JMenuItem("Option");
```

So I add everything to the bar and to the menu:

```
menuBar.add(fileMenu);
fileMenu.add(creditsItem);
fileMenu.add(preferenceItem);
```

Then I want perform different actions depending which of the two ItemMenu in clicked, in particular I want open two differents **JDialog**

```
creditsItem.addMouseListener(this);
preferenceItem.addMouseListener(this);
```

After implementing **MouseListener**

```
class MainFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener
```

I have to use

```
@Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Clicked!!");
    }
```

But the problem is recognizing which of the two **JMenuItem** has been clicked. I've tought of using switch, but how to know which of the two is clicked is the problem.

Comment: you can use this 
[Mouselistener][1]

http://java-program-sample.blogspot.in/2011/09/implementing-event-listener-on.html
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589605/menulistener-implementation-how-to-detect-which-jmenu-was-clicked

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know about MenuListener and so I didn't found this question, Thank you!

Comment: @Shriam addMenuListener works only for JMenu and not for JMenuItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is

```
@Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource()==preferenceItem){
        System.out.println("PreferenceItem");
        optionDialog = new OptionDialog();
        }
        if(e.getSource()==printItem){
        System.out.println("PrintItem");
        }

    }
```

after implementing MouseListener instead of MenuListener