# JMenu addmenulistener

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to use Jmenu as buttons to change what is showed in the frame but when the menu is selected the selection is not released. Below is the code for Jmenu instance and it changes the location of two fields and labels.

```
mnAddUser.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                lblUserId.setBounds(150, 86, 111, 30);
                userIDField.setBounds(273, 80, 268, 43);    

                lblUserName.setBounds(150, 165, 111, 30);
                userNameField.setBounds(273, 159, 268, 43);

                lblUserName.setVisible(true);
                userNameField.setVisible(true);

                btnAddUser.setBounds(187, 235, 150, 43);
                btnReset.setBounds(390, 235, 150, 43);

                btnAddUser.setText("Add User");
            }

            @Override
            public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }           

        });
```

Comment: Can you paste your code please?

Comment: i added the code for Jmenu

Comment: `setBounds(...)` just forget about ever using that and learn how to use `LayoutManager`'s. Trust me, it will save you lots of time, make your code cleaner, simpler and will work better across different platforms.

Comment: don't understand why you are fiddling with a menulistener - instead add actions to the menu and be happy

Answer (score 1):

- maybe there no reason to use [JMenu added to JMenuBar and listening by MenuListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9862855/714968)
- simple to add [JButtons to the JMenuBar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8127463/714968), maybe to use `JButton.setFocusable(false);`