# Exit Menu using ActionListener is not working

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, jmenu

I'm trying to exit menu using the ActionListener, however my code doesn't work properly and the "Quit the Program" button doesn't do anything. Below is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.JMenu;
 import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
 import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
 import javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem;
 import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
 import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
 import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JTextArea;
 import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;

 public class testCoinSorterGUI extends testCoinSorter{

JTextArea output;
JScrollPane scrollPane;

public JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu menu, submenu;
    JMenuItem menuItem;
    JRadioButtonMenuItem rbMenuItem;
    JCheckBoxMenuItem cbMenuItem;

    //Create the menu bar.
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    //Build the first menu.
    menu = new JMenu("Calculator");
    menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
            "The only menu in this program that has menu items");
    menuBar.add(menu);
    
    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Coin calculator");
    menu.add(menuItem);
    
    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Multi Coin calculator");
    menu.add(menuItem);

    //Build second menu in the menu bar.
    menu = new JMenu("Print coin list");
    menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
    menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("This menu does nothing");
    menuBar.add(menu);

    //Build third menu in the menu bar.
    menu = new JMenu("Set details");
    menuBar.add(menu);

    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Set currency");
    menu.add(menuItem);

    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Set minimum coin input value");
    menu.add(menuItem);

    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Set maximum coin input value");
    menu.add(menuItem);
    menu.addSeparator();

    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Display program configurations");
    menu.add(menuItem);

    //Build fifth menu in the menu bar.
    menu = new JMenu("Quit the program");
    menuBar.add(menu);
    menu.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    );
    
    return menuBar;
}

public Container createContentPane() {
    //Create the content-pane-to-be.
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    contentPane.setOpaque(true);

    //Create a scrolled text area.
    output = new JTextArea(5, 30);
    output.setEditable(false);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(output);

    //Add the text area to the content pane.
    contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    return contentPane;
}

/** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = testCoinSorterGUI.class.getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("*** CoinSorterGUI ***");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    testCoinSorterGUI demo = new testCoinSorterGUI();
    frame.setJMenuBar(demo.createMenuBar());
    frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

    //Display the window.
    frame.setSize(680, 480);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Currently I only want to test the "quit the program" button, so please ignore all the other menu. Any help would be appreciated, I am really stucked though I think I have put the code in the correct order.

Comment: A `JMenu` isn't considered and "actionable" item.  You need to add a `JMenuItem` to a `JMenu` and then it can be actioned.  This is by design.  Or, if you really don't like your users, you could do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862165/jmenu-actionlistener)

Comment: A problem of this nature does not require >130 LOC to demonstrate the problem. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use this instead of the ActionListener, which is supposed to be use for a different range of controls:

```
JMenu quitProgramMenu = new JMenu("Quit the program");

quitProgramMenu.addMenuListener(
 new MenuListener() {

  @Override
  public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
   System.exit(0);
  }

  @Override
  public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {}

  @Override
  public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {}
 }
);
menuBar.add(quitProgramMenu);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
JMenu quitProgramMenu = new JMenu("Quit the program");

quitProgramMenu .addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        
        
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
            
        }
        
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
        
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
        
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
    });
menuBar.add(quitProgramMenu);
```