# Change the background's color of RibbonApplicationMenuEntryPrimary (Flamingo)

Tags: java, swing, menu, ribbon, radiance-flamingo

Is the any way to change the background's color of RibbonApplicationMenuEntryPrimary (Flamingo)?

I looked at  its javadoc but couldn't find the way to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Please, with due respect, I [checked the APIs](https://github.com/Insubstantial/insubstantial/tree/master/flamingo); there are lot of  imports and extends from lots of different methods, starting with `java.swing.BasicButtonUI`, ([here is my attemp to override MetalButtonUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/714968)).

2) Maybe it would be easy to change the built_in color theme, but I don't suggest doing that.

3) I'm not a Flamingo or Netbeans 7 user, but the following tutorials are available:

- Flamingo tutorial on [Java geek](http://blog.frankel.ch/flamingo-tutorial) / [javalobby.dzone](http://java.dzone.com/articles/flamingo-tutorial)
- Substance look and feel forked in [Insubstantial](http://shemnon.com/speling/2011/04/insubstantial-62-release.html)
- [NetBeans Platform Ribbon Bar Integration Tutorial](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-ribbonbar.html#customize-appmenu)

everywhere is mentioned support for Substance L&F

3) I'd use built-in themes from the Substance Look and Feel (I'm Substance user), but

4) Before downloading the source code for Substance, there is a working example for `Swing Look and Feels` in the Java Folder `test` in `Check.java`,

- There you can test and choose built-in Substance themes from menus, as well as
- Test (you have to download the JAR files first) all good Java Swing Look and Feels inside of one JFrame.