# How do I use Flamingo and Insubstantial?

Tags: java, swing, ribbon, look-and-feel, radiance-flamingo

I have only used Swing so far for designing some sub-standard GUI.

I was planning on using `Flamingo` to get the Ribbon look and feel of MS Word. I was directed to the website of Insubstantial. http://shemnon.com/speling/2011/04/insubstantial-62-release.html

I want to ask: **do I only need to download the jar file and add it to  my build path in Eclipse?** or is there anything else I need to do ?

Comment: by default only to add jar to the classpath, [not sure if needed trident.jar too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10131627/714968), Substance required trident

Comment: what happened when you tried ;-) Afair, they come with examples (or else you can find examples on the net)