# Is there a premade java library that emulates the Office Ribbon Customizer?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, package

I'm trying to implement the 'Ribbon Customizer' from the Microsoft Office suite into a swing product. To refresh your memory, or show you for the first time, the customizer I'm referring to looks like so (with the obligatory hand drawn circles):

[image: Ribbon Customizer from Office]

I could probably spend a good few weeks of my own time trying to make a robust class to draw this, as it's only two scroll panes, and a few buttons. But I don't want to re-invent the wheel, when my wheel would probably end up at least a little wonky.

For some background, it's going to in the future allow users to select which sheets get added to an output Excel Workbook.

Does this sort of Component exist in a package somewhere I can just include in my project? Does this sort of element have a standard name? I've tried googling for images and java packages but to no avail, the closest I found was this [SWT 'Widget'](http://hexapixel.com/projects/ribbon), but that only emulates the Ribbon, not the customizer.

Comment: [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10131627/714968)

Comment: @mKorbel I'm not sure what use that is supposed to me :? I'm not implementing the Ribbon, that I found myself. I'm looking for a component ***like*** the customizer here, with two arbitrary lists. Nothing to do with the Ribbon.

Comment: You might get better (or any) answers if you asked what this UI pattern is named over at UX.SE, then edited your question to use that name.  From the title I was ready to link you to a Swing ribbon implementation, which is clearly not what you want.