# java - how do jcomponents draw?

Tags: java, swing, repaint, jcomponent

im wondering how a jcomponent gets painted on the screen, is it painted inside paintComponent() from Graphics? Or is it painted separately. Im asking this because its weird how a jbutton changes color on mousehover even though repaint() is never called.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: 1) *"im wondering how a jcomponent gets.."*  I'm wondering if your keyboard has a shift key.  If so, please use it at the start of sentences, and where appropriate for things like `JComponent`.  It makes the text easier to read.  2) It is a good idea to add the Swing tag to Swing related questions.

Comment: But `repaint()` certainly *is* called, although maybe not in the way you're imagining it. It may be the JButton's delegate that has repaint called on it. Please read [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html) for some of the details on painting mechanics.

Comment: Sorry Im on kindle fire so its hard for me to do it, but ill try my best.

Comment: So it's called separately from paintComponent()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Component`s are painted with their [`paint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method. `repaint` is just a useful method that will call `paint` at some point in the near future on the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

---

When the mouse enters a `JButton`, the following method is called (for `JButton`s with a default UI):

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    AbstractButton b = (AbstractButton) e.getSource();
    ButtonModel model = b.getModel();
    if (b.isRolloverEnabled() && !SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
        model.setRollover(true);
    }
    if (model.isPressed())
            model.setArmed(true);
}
```

[`ButtonModel.setRollover`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html) will fire a `ChangeEvent`, which is handled by `AbstractButton` in the following way:

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();

    updateMnemonicProperties();
    if (isEnabled() != model.isEnabled()) {
        setEnabled(model.isEnabled());
    }
    fireStateChanged();
    repaint();
}
```

So `repaint` *is* called when the mouse enters a `JButton`.

Comment: Ok does the repaint() only apply for the JButton itself or all other JComponents and paintComponent()?

Comment: @Ewen `repaint` is a method of all `Component`s. `repaint` will call `paint`, which will in turn call `paintComponent` among other painting methods.

Comment: Thanks, i believe this is the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

> ..a jbutton changes color on mousehover even though repaint() is never called.

Sure it is.  And this code is evidence of that.  Of course, it is not evidence on a Kindle Fire that most probably has no JRE, but then, a Kindle Fire is an entirely inappropriate tool to be using to communicate to a Q&A site while discussing technical points of a programming language that does not run on the device.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonRepaint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override 
            public void run() {
                JButton b = new JButton("Hover Over Me!") {
                    @Override
                    public void repaint() {
                        super.repaint();
                        System.out.println("Repaint");
                    }
                };
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, b);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, discussing technical points on a mobile device is generally not the best idea.

Comment: @Hover I was responding to the exact statement *"a jbutton changes color on mousehover even though repaint() is never called."* admittedly I read 'mousehover' as 'mouse over' since the Kindle typing was making my eyes water.  Is there some specific inclusion of `paintComponent(Graphics)` I should consider?  BTW - liked your comment as to why this type of question should not be asked from a Kindle.  This series of questions seems to be tying up a lot of our time.

Comment: Im sorry but i cant use my computer and this is the only way.

Comment: *"Ok what is the code for?"*  Try to figure it out when you get to a desktop that has a decent keyboard and a JDK.  I (and a plethora of others) are wasting too much time on this.  *"i cant use my computer"* Not my problem, and not a sufficient excuse for wasting the time of others.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the `paint()` method that gets called belongs to the button's UI delegate, typically derived from [`BasicButtonUI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicButtonUI.html). There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/230513) using `MetalButtonUI`.