# How to change appearance of pressed/clicked/selected button in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, selected

I'd like to change the appearance of a button when it's in pressed/clicked/selected state.

To be more specific, I'd like to change it's border to `BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder()` when it' is pressed/clicked/selected.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the code below. It sets the border when pressed and resets it when released. You can also do this on `mouseEntered` / `mouseExited`.

```
button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
  }

  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    button.setBorder(null);
  }
});
```

Comment: It's so simple that now I'm ashamed that I didn't think about it by myself. But it solves half of my problem - to be more specific "pressed/clicked" one. Do you know maybe how can I do it with "selected" state? (I probably should mention at start that this state concerns JToggleButton) Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: OK I found this one myself already. If someone would like to know here's the answer:

`public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (isSelected()) {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
    } else {
        setBorder(null);
    }
}`

But thanks for your help **Dan**, you helped me a lot!

Comment: @AncientBehemoth Thanks for the setBorder(null) for removing the Bevel border.

Answer (score 2):

Have look at [ButtonModel for JButtons JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), there are [implemented all your requierements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/714968)