# Changing the background of JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a Swing JButton and I'm also using the following code for my project:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Now when trying to change the background for one button using `btnNewButton.setBackground(Color.RED);` it doesn't turn red, only the borders turn red.

How can I turn this background to red while still using `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()` for the rest of the components/project?

Comment: Does your button have a icon(image)? If so, the background does turn red but is hidden by the icon of the button, giving the impression that only the "borders" are changed.

Comment: hmm, even without the icon it still happens so it's not that. As long as I have UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); only the borders change color...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at bug [4880747 : XP L&F: REGRESSION: setBackground on JButton sets border color in Windows XP](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4880747). Evaluation section states:

> Changing the appearance of a button can always cause conflicts with
> the current L&F implementation. The Windows L&F for Swing tries to be
> as close as possible to the native display. On XP, we use the built-in
> bitmap resources for the  buttons. These can not be colorized, just
> like in the native API.
>
> You should call setContentAreaFilled(false) on the button to avoid
> having the L&F paint its decorations. This has the side effect that
> the button's opaque property is set to false, so you need to follow
> that call with a call to setOpaque(true).
>
> This is not a bug and will be closed.

As stated, `setContentAreaFilled(false)` and `setOpaque(true)` will do the trick, but the button will look different.

If it worth the trouble you can create you own `ButtonUI`. Here is a great [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/1048330) by @mKorbel that you may find useful.

Comment: This is quite late, but I still feel the need to leave a thank-you message. This helped me. :)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you want to achieve.

You could use `JButton#setContentAreaFilled` passing it false, but you, probably also need to call `JButton#setBorderPainted` passing it falls

You could also change the `UIManager`'s default value for the buttons background

Comment: If we set `UIManager`'s default value then this change will be reflected for all `Jbuttons`..Isn't there any way to change the background of only one `JButton`?

Comment: Not really, while maintains the look of the button

Comment: +1 for `setContentAreaFilled`. It looks funny with `WindowsLookAndFeel` though :)

Comment: @VishalK I did think that you could provide your own UI delegate, but would mean you need to provide one for each possible look and feel you want to use, that's a lot of work

Answer (score 0):

You should make the `JButton` opaque:

```
btnNewButton.setOpaque(true);
```

As specified for [`JComponent#setBackground`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29) method in oracle documentation:

> Sets the background color of this component. The background color is
>   used only if the component is opaque, and only by subclasses of
>   JComponent or ComponentUI implementations. Direct subclasses of
>   JComponent must override paintComponent to honor this property.
>
> **It is up to the look and feel to honor this property, some may choose
>   to ignore it.**

I think that the current look and feel does not support this property..That's why the background color is ignored in this case.