# My custom Look And Feel implementation does not seem to work

Tags: java, swing, custom-component, look-and-feel, uimanager

I would like to create my own Look and Feel and have derived the MetalLookAndFeel. I have setup a very basic configuration where all files are in the same directory and have not a package declaration:

MyLookAndFeel.java

```
import javax.swing.UIDefaults;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel;


public class MyLookAndFeel extends MetalLookAndFeel {

    public MyLookAndFeel() {
        setCurrentTheme(new DefaultMetalTheme());
    }

    @Override
    protected void initClassDefaults(UIDefaults table) {
        super.initClassDefaults(table);

        table.put( "ButtonUI", "MyButtonUI");
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "MyLookAndFeel";
    }

    @Override
    public String getID() {
        return "MyLookAndFeel";
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "MyLookAndFeel";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNativeLookAndFeel() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSupportedLookAndFeel() {
         return true;
    }
}
```

And we also have the MyButtonUI.java:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalButtonUI;


public class MyButtonUI extends MetalButtonUI {

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintButtonPressed(Graphics g, AbstractButton b) {
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintText(Graphics g, AbstractButton b, Rectangle textRect,
            String text) {
    }
}
```

With the above code I expect that a weird button is going to be painted (or no button at all since the `paint` method is empty) when I run the `TestUI JFrame` class with this constructor, but the button looks quiet normal:

```
public TestUI() throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new MyLookAndFeel());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(200,200);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(new JButton("Press"));
        add(new JLabel("Text"));
        setVisible(true);
    }
```

Have I forgotten something important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `"MyButtonUI"` should be full path (same as for Icon packaged in jar) or valid class name e.g. `UIManager.put("ButtonUI", MyButtonUI.class.getName());`
- override `BasicButtonUI`, with interfaces to another LaFs, can be empty, without override all methods for all `System LaFs`, instead of `MetalButtonUI`, your custom `MetalButtonUI` is so LaF sensitive, breakable, in the case that is registred in `UIManager`
- maybe [will help you partial workaround for MetalButtonUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/714968), maybe there isn't reason to register custom UI to `UIManager`, sure final decision is up tu you

Comment: MyButtonUI is in the same path as the MyLookAndFeel and TestUI classes (on root directory level, that is no package declared). I will check the link you posted.

Comment: @Rox wrote `MyButtonUI is in the same path as the MyLookAndFeel and TestUI classes (on root directory level, that is no package declared).` not then there isn't accesible I meaning `UIManager.put("ButtonUI", MyButtonUI.class.getName());`

Answer (score 1):

In your class MyButtonUI you have to implement a public static method createUI(). Like this:

```
public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c)
{
    return new MyButtonUI ();
}
```

Or return one shared instance for all the buttons.