# When button is clicked, I want the button background to change

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

So I when I click on a button on my JFrame, I want the button to change it's background as long as it clicked. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Have not tried out anything out yet. I'm a rookie. So I have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html try out something and if you face any problem than ask question.

Answer (score 2):

*When button is clicked, I want the button background to change*

Before button is pressed:

[image]

after button is pressed:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createAndShowJFrame();
    }

    public static void createAndShowJFrame() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                JFrame frame = createJFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    private static JFrame createJFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                JButton btn = ((JButton) ae.getSource());//get the button that was clicked

                //set its background and foreground
                btn.setBackground(Color.RED);
                btn.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            }
        };

        JButton b = new JButton("Test");
        b.addActionListener(al);

        frame.add(b);

        frame.pack();

        return frame;
    }
}
```

Comment: @WhiplashOne see  [JButton.getModel.addChangeListener](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/714968), or the same method is implemented in JButton API, isPressed

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by multiple ways. The following is the sample snippet for apply a button select color for all buttons.

```
UIManager.put("Button.select", new ColorUIResource(255, 0, 0));
JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
JFrame frame = new JFrame("JButton select color");
frame.add(button);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(300, 80);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: 1) Swing components should be created and manipulated on EDT. 2) calling `setSize` of `JFrame` is not recommended practice, use `LayoutManager` instead and call `pack()` in place of `setSize`. 3) Rather `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` or it will completely exit the app regardless of other windows or threads open. 4) OP does not say for all buttons (but of course he/she might have just ommitted that)

Comment: +1  though as Im not sure if OP wants button to change after click, or only while button is held down