# Overriding JButton paintComponent with differnet style not suporting HTML format

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I just want to set different style for JButton. So I overridden the paintComponent to achieve. It works successful but this button doesn't support the HTML format.

could you please suggest me

```
paintComponent()
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
this is below my override code:
// prep for painting.  
      Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;
      if(buttonStyle != 0 && buttonStyle != IMAGES){
        if(g == null)
            return;
        if(getBackground() == null)
          setBackground(acrcolor);
        if(getFadedBackgroundColor() == null)
          setFadedBackgroundColor(Color.white);

        g2D.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth()+getX(), getHeight()+getY());
        // end prep for painting.
      }
      switch (buttonStyle){
      case SKINZ:
        paintSkinz(g2D);
        return;
      case IMAGES:
        paintImages(g2D);
        break;
      case ROLLOVER:
        System.err.println("Rollover look of FuelButton not yet implemented.");
        break;
      case JAVA_LIKE:
        paintJavaLike(g2D);
        return;
      case GRADIENCE:
        paintGradience(g2D);
      case CLASSIC:
      case JAVA_DEFAULT:
      default:          
        super.paintComponent(g);
        m_originalborder = getBorder();
        m_originalfont = getFont();
        return;
      }
      paintText(g2D,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());


paintJavaLike(g2D):
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
g2D.setColor(getBackground());
      g2D.fill3DRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),true);
      if(getIcon()==null)
        paintText(g2D,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
      else if (getText() == null || getText().length() == 0)
        this.paintCenteredIcon(g2D, ((ImageIcon)getIcon()).getImage());
      else {
        int w = getWidth() - getIconTextGap() - getIcon().getIconWidth() - (borderWidth*2)-4;
        int h = getHeight()-(borderWidth*2);
        g2D.drawImage(((ImageIcon)getIcon()).getImage(), 2, (getHeight()/2)-(getIcon().getIconHeight()/2), this);
        paintText(g2D,2+getIcon().getIconWidth()+this.getIconTextGap(),0,w,h);
      }
```

thanks
Palanisamy

Answer (score 1):

You could provide a custom [ButtonUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/ButtonUI.html), and use that for the buttons, instead of overriding `paintComponent()`. Swing uses `TextLayout` for drawing the strings, and that can get complicated. However, [BasicButtonUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicButtonUI.html) has a protected `paintText()` method that can do what you want (you don't necessarily need to call it manually. The UI's `paint()` calls it, unless you override that too). So if you extend `BasicButtonUI` you can simply let it draw the string.

Comment: [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751311/creating-a-custom-button-in-java-with-jbutton/5755124#5755124)