# JButton dynamic Background & foreground change

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, custom-component

I want to change the background and foreground dynamically swipe and i am using below custom button. 
The button style is set it as default.
Could any plz help me out?

```
public class CustomButton extends JButton {
        private int buttonStyle = JAVA_DEFAULT;

    public static final int JAVA_DEFAULT      = 0;
    public static final int SKINZ             = 1;
    public static final int CLASSIC           = 2;
    public static final int IMAGES            = 3;
    public static final int ROLLOVER          = 4;
    public static final int GRADIENCE         = 5;
    public static final int JAVA_LIKE         = 6;  // A java-look button with our own text handling.

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
      // prep for painting.
      Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;
      if(buttonStyle != 0 && buttonStyle != IMAGES){
        if(g == null)
            return;
        if(getBackground() == null)
          setBackground(color);
        if(getFadedBackgroundColor() == null)
          setFadedBackgroundColor(Color.white);

        g2D.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth()+getX(), getHeight()+getY());
        // end prep for painting.
      }
      switch (buttonStyle){
      case SKINZ:
        paintSkinz(g2D);
        return;
      case IMAGES:
        paintImages(g2D);
        break;
      case ROLLOVER:
        System.err.println("Rollover look of CustomButton not yet implemented.");
        break;
      case JAVA_LIKE:
        paintJavaLike(g2D);
        return;
      case GRADIENCE:
        paintGradience(g2D);
      case CLASSIC:
      case JAVA_DEFAULT:
      default:
        super.paintComponent(g);
        m_originalborder = getBorder();
        m_originalfont = getFont();
        return;
      }
      paintText(g2D,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
    }

     private void paintJavaLike(Graphics2D g2D)
    {
      g2D.setColor(getBackground());
      g2D.fill3DRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),true);
      if(getIcon()==null)
        paintText(g2D,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
      else if (getText() == null || getText().length() == 0)
        this.paintCenteredIcon(g2D, ((ImageIcon)getIcon()).getImage());
      else {
        int w = getWidth() - getIconTextGap() - getIcon().getIconWidth() - (borderWidth*2)-4;
        int h = getHeight()-(borderWidth*2);
        g2D.drawImage(((ImageIcon)getIcon()).getImage(), 2, (getHeight()/2)-(getIcon().getIconHeight()/2), this);
        paintText(g2D,2+getIcon().getIconWidth()+this.getIconTextGap(),0,w,h);
      }
    }

    public void paintText(Graphics2D g2D, int offset_x, int offset_y, int width, int height)
    {
      int idx,x,y,strwidth,strwidth2=0, strHeight=0;
      String myText,myText2=null;
      Font myFont;
      FontMetrics fm;

      myText = getText();
      myFont = getFont();
      if (m_FontSize > 0 && myFont.getSize() != m_FontSize)
        myFont = myFont.deriveFont((float)m_FontSize);

      fm = g2D.getFontMetrics(myFont);
      strwidth = fm.stringWidth(myText);
      strHeight = fm.getAscent() + fm.getDescent();

      // Handle font scaling and line wrapping
      if (strwidth > width || strHeight > height)
      {
        idx = myText.indexOf(' ');

        // Only one word, shrink font to fit.
        if (idx == -1)
        {
          if (m_FontSize == -1)
          {
            while((strwidth > width || strHeight > height) && myFont.getSize() > m_MinimumFontSize)
            {
              myFont = myFont.deriveFont((float)(myFont.getSize()-1));
              fm = g2D.getFontMetrics(myFont);
              strwidth = fm.stringWidth(myText);
              strHeight = fm.getAscent() + fm.getDescent();
            }
          } else {
            strwidth = fm.stringWidth(myText);
          }
        }
        else   // Multiple words
        {
          // Split words up.  This could be enhanced in the future.
          // Currently limited to two words split on the first space.
          if (m_TextWrapOn)    // Only if allowing text wrapping.
          {
            myText2 = myText.substring(idx+1);
            myText  = myText.substring(0,idx);
          }
          strwidth = fm.stringWidth(myText);
          strwidth2 = fm.stringWidth(myText2);
          strHeight = (fm.getAscent() + fm.getDescent()) * 2;  // *2 lines.
          if (m_FontSize == -1)
          {
            while((strwidth > width || strwidth2 > width || strHeight > height) &&
                  myFont.getSize() > m_MinimumFontSize)
            {
              myFont = myFont.deriveFont((float)(myFont.getSize()-1));
              fm = g2D.getFontMetrics(myFont);
              strwidth = fm.stringWidth(myText);
              strwidth2 = fm.stringWidth(myText2);
              strHeight = (fm.getAscent() + fm.getDescent()) * 2;  // *2 lines.
            }
          } else {
            strwidth = fm.stringWidth(myText);
            strwidth2 = fm.stringWidth(myText2);
          }
        }
      }
      // Scale text larger
      else if (strwidth < (width * 0.75)) {
        if (m_FontSize == -1)
        {
          while((strwidth < (width * 0.8)) && (fm.getHeight() < height) &&
                myFont.getSize() < m_MaximumFontSize)
          {
            myFont = myFont.deriveFont((float)(myFont.getSize()+1));
            fm = g2D.getFontMetrics(myFont);
            strwidth = fm.stringWidth(myText);
          }
        } else {
          strwidth = fm.stringWidth(myText);
        }
      }

      if (myText2 == null)
        y = (height/2)+(fm.getMaxAscent()/2)+offset_y;
      else
        y = (height/2)-fm.getDescent()+offset_y;
      if (y < fm.getAscent())
        y = fm.getAscent();
      if (y > height)
        y = height;                      // Don't put chars off bottom of button
      if (buttonStyle == JAVA_LIKE && y == height)
        y = height-2;                    // subtract border

      switch(getHorizontalAlignment())
      {
        case SwingUtilities.LEFT:
          x = 14 + offset_x;
          break;
        case SwingUtilities.RIGHT:
          x = width-strwidth-14+offset_x;
          break;
        case SwingUtilities.CENTER:
        default:
          // the computations here are centering the text.
          x = (width/2)-(strwidth/2)+offset_x;
          break;
      }
      if (x < offset_x) x = offset_x;
      if (this.buttonStyle == JAVA_LIKE && x < (offset_x+1)) x = offset_x+1;

      // go ahead and draw text.
      // prep for painting text
      if (model.isPressed())
        g2D.setColor(getBackground());
      else
        g2D.setColor(getForeground());
      g2D.setFont(myFont);
      g2D.drawString(myText, x, y);

      if (myText2 != null)
      {
        y = (height/2)+fm.getHeight()-fm.getDescent()+offset_y;
        switch(getHorizontalAlignment())
        {
          case SwingUtilities.LEFT:
            // the computations here are centering the text.
            x = borderWidth + getIconTextGap() + offset_x;
            break;
          case SwingUtilities.RIGHT:
            // the computations here are centering the text.
            x = width-strwidth2-(borderWidth+getIconTextGap())+offset_x;
            break;
          case SwingUtilities.CENTER:
          default:
            // the computations here are centering the text.
            x = (width/2)-(strwidth2/2)+offset_x;
            break;
        }
        if (x < offset_x) x = offset_x;
        g2D.drawString(myText2, x, y);
      }
    }

   public void paintOffCenterIcon(Graphics2D g2D, Image image){
      int w = getIcon().getIconWidth();
      int h = getIcon().getIconHeight();
      g2D.drawImage(image, (getWidth()/2)-(w/2)+2 , (getHeight()/2)-(h/2)+2, this);
    }

    public void paintCenteredIcon(Graphics2D g2D, Image image){
      int w = getIcon().getIconWidth();
      int h = getIcon().getIconHeight();
      g2D.drawImage(image, (getWidth()/2)-(w/2), (getHeight()/2)-(h/2), this);
    }

    public void paintGradience(Graphics2D g2D)
    {
      GradientPaint gradientp;
      switch(m_shape){
      case RECTANGLE:
        //stuff for round rectangles
        gradientp = new GradientPaint(m_X1, m_Y1, getBackground(),
            m_X2, m_Y2, getFadedBackgroundColor());
        g2D.setPaint(gradientp);
        g2D.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), arc, arc);
        break;
      case OVAL:
        //stuff for ovals
        gradientp = new GradientPaint(m_X1, m_Y1, getBackground(),
            m_X2, m_Y2, getFadedBackgroundColor());
        g2D.setPaint(gradientp);
        g2D.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        break;
      case POLYGON:
        // stuff for triangles
        int xs[] = {0, (int)m_X2, (int)m_Y2};
        int ys[] = {0, (int)m_X2/2, (int)m_Y2};
        g2D.fillPolygon(xs , ys, 3);
        break;
      }
    }

    public void paintSkinz(Graphics2D g2D){
      m_shape = RECTANGLE;  //just for clarity's sake.

      if(getModel().isPressed()){
        beveledPressed(g2D);
        g2D.setClip(null);
        return;
      }
      else if(!getModel().isPressed()){
        beveledUnpressed(g2D);
        g2D.setClip(null);
      }
    }

    public void paintImages(Graphics2D g2D){
      m_shape = RECTANGLE;  //just for clarity's sake.
      Icon icon;

      if(getModel().isPressed()){
        icon = getPressedIcon();
        if(icon!=null)
          paintCenteredIcon(g2D, ((ImageIcon)icon).getImage());
        g2D.setClip(null);
        return;
      }
      else if(!getModel().isPressed()){
        icon = getIcon();
        if(icon!=null)
          paintCenteredIcon(g2D, ((ImageIcon)icon).getImage());
        g2D.setClip(null);
      }
    }

   public void setPreferredSize(Dimension prefSz)
    {
      m_PreferredSize = prefSz;
      super.setPreferredSize(prefSz);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
      if (m_PreferredSize != null)
        return m_PreferredSize;
      int insets = borderWidth*2 + 4;      // initial border width and insets;
      switch (buttonStyle)
      {
        case JAVA_LIKE:
          int width  = insets;
          int height = insets;
          if (this.getGraphics() == null || this.getGraphics().getFontMetrics() == null)   // safety net
            return super.getPreferredSize();
          if (this.getText() != null)
          {
            width  += this.getGraphics().getFontMetrics().stringWidth(getText());
            height += this.getGraphics().getFontMetrics().getHeight();
          }
          if (this.getIcon() != null)
          {
            width  += getIcon().getIconWidth();
            if (getText() != null)
              width += this.getIconTextGap();
            if (height < (getIcon().getIconHeight()+insets))
              height = getIcon().getIconHeight();
          }
          return new Dimension(width,height);
        case SKINZ:
        case CLASSIC:
        case IMAGES:
        case ROLLOVER:
        case GRADIENCE:
        case JAVA_DEFAULT:
        default:
          return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
    }

   void dButtonStateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
    {
        // Call 'super' methods in here.  Don't call the overriden versions.
        if (this.getModel().isRollover())
        {
            if (rolloverBackground != null)
                super.setBackground(rolloverBackground);
            if (rolloverForeground != null)
                super.setForeground(rolloverForeground);
            if (rolloverFont != null)
                super.setFont(rolloverFont);
        }
        else
        {
            super.setBackground(normalBackground);
            super.setForeground(normalForeground);
            super.setFont(normalFont);
        }
    } // end dButtonStateChanged()


    protected void fireActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
      if (event != null)
        super.fireActionPerformed( event);
      if (m_Key != null)
      {
        // just a hack to get this working with the Java Client.
        if (m_ui == null){
          m_ui = getClientUI();
        } // end hack.

      }
    }

    void jbInit()
    {
      setBackground(color); // sets default bg color.
      setForeground(Color.black); //sets default foreground to black
      if(buttonStyle != JAVA_DEFAULT )
        setBorder(null);

      enableEvents(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
      enableEvents(FocusEvent.FOCUS_EVENT_MASK);
      enableEvents(ActionEvent.ACTION_EVENT_MASK);
      enableEvents(KeyEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);

      // Sets up a listener for state changes on this button.
      this.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
      {
          public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
        {
            dButtonStateChanged(e);
        }
      });
    } // end jbInit()

    protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e)
    {
      switch(e.getID()) {
      // these are for future development.
      case MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED:
      case MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED:
        super.processMouseEvent(e);
        break;
      case MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED:
      case MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED:
        e.consume();
        break;
      case MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED:
        // we call doClick() b/c we may not get a MOUSE_RELEASED event with a
        // touchscreen so we need to make sure it gets sent, and the doClick()
        // method does that.
        doClick(80);
        e.consume();
        break;
      }
    }


    protected void processFocusEvent(FocusEvent e)
    {
      super.processFocusEvent(e);
      switch (e.getID())
      {
      case FocusEvent.FOCUS_LOST:
      //if (m_ui != null)
      //  m_ui.getFieldManager().setCurrentField(null);
        break;
      case FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED:
        if (m_ui != null)
          m_ui.getFieldManager().setCurrentField(this); // Tell manager I got the focus.
        break;
      }
    }

    private void beveledUnpressed(Graphics2D g){
      // so, we've got a hashtable of images we've drawn.  We'll try to get this image out or it.
      BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage)m_imagetable.get("UnPressed."+"SKINZ"+"."+
                          getBackground().toString()+"."+getSize().toString());
      Graphics2D g2D;

      int w = getWidth();
      int h = getHeight();
      //define some border sizes
      /*
       * todo: fix this, i don't like this being hardcoded.
       * */
      if(borderWidth == 0)
        borderWidth = 10;
      int borderheight = borderWidth;
      Rectangle innerRect = new Rectangle(borderWidth, borderheight, w-(borderWidth*2), h-(borderheight*2));

      // if we didn't find this image in the hashtable, we'll draw the image.
      if(bi == null){
        bi = (BufferedImage) createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2D = bi.createGraphics();

        Color shadowcolor = getBackground().darker();
        // would like to have gotten lightcolor with the brighter() method, but that
        // method doesn't always produce a color different from the original color.
        Color lightcolor = Color.white;

        //sets of polygon points
        int leftXpoints[]   = {0, borderWidth, borderWidth, 0};
        int leftYpoints[]   = {0, borderheight, h-borderheight, h};
        int topXpoints[]    = {0, w, w-borderWidth, borderWidth};
        int topYpoints[]    = {0, 0, borderheight, borderheight};
        int rightXpoints[]  = {w, w, w-borderWidth, w-borderWidth};
        int rightYpoints[]  = {0, h, h-borderheight, borderheight};
        int bottomXpoints[] = {borderWidth, w-borderWidth, w, 0};
        int bottomYpoints[] = {h-borderheight, h-borderheight, h, h};

        //define polys
        Polygon leftpoly   = new Polygon(leftXpoints,   leftYpoints,   4);
        Polygon toppoly    = new Polygon(topXpoints,    topYpoints,    4);
        Polygon rightpoly  = new Polygon(rightXpoints,  rightYpoints,  4);
        Polygon bottompoly = new Polygon(bottomXpoints, bottomYpoints, 4);

        //draw the right-hand beveled edge
        g2D.setClip(rightpoly);
        GradientPaint p = new GradientPaint(w-borderWidth, 0, getBackground(),
            w, 0, shadowcolor);
        g2D.setPaint(p);
        g2D.fillRoundRect(0, 0, w, h, arc, arc);

        //draw the bottom-hand beveled edge
        g2D.setClip(bottompoly);
        p = new GradientPaint(0, h-borderheight,
                              getBackground(), 0,
                              h, shadowcolor);
        g2D.setPaint(p);
        g2D.fillRoundRect(0, 0, w, h, arc,
                          arc);

        //draw the left-hand beveled edge
        g2D.setClip(leftpoly);
        p = new GradientPaint(0, 0,
                              lightcolor, borderWidth,
                              0, getBackground());
        g2D.setPaint(p);
        g2D.fillRoundRect(0, 0, w, h, arc,
                          arc);

        //draw the top-hand beveled edge
        g2D.setClip(toppoly);
        p = new GradientPaint(0, 0,
                              lightcolor, 0,
                              borderheight, getBackground());
        g2D.setPaint(p);
        g2D.fillRoundRect(0, 0, w, h, arc,
                          arc);

        //now draw inner rectangle
        g2D.setClip(innerRect);
        g2D.setColor(getBackground());
        g2D.fill(innerRect);

        g.drawImage(bi, null, getX(), getY());
        // we only want to draw each image once, so we'll throw this image in the hash table.
        m_imagetable.put("UnPressed."+"SKINZ"+"."+getBackground().toString()+"."+getSize().toString(), bi);
      }
      else {
        g2D = (Graphics2D)bi.getGraphics();
      }

      g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);

      innerRect.x -=6;
      innerRect.width += 12;
      g.setClip(innerRect);

      // icons take precedence over text.
      if(getIcon()==null)
        paintText(g,innerRect.x,innerRect.y,innerRect.width,innerRect.height);
      else
        paintCenteredIcon(g, ((ImageIcon)getIcon()).getImage());
    }


    private void beveledPressed(Graphics2D g){
      // so, we've got a hashtable of images we've drawn.  We'll try to get this image out or it.
      BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage)m_imagetable.get("Pressed."+"SKINZ"+"."+
                          getBackground().toString()+"."+getSize().toString());
      Graphics2D g2D;

      int w = getWidth();
      int h = getHeight();
      //define some border sizes
      /*
       * todo: fix this, i don't like this being hardcoded.
       * */
      if(borderWidth == 0)
        borderWidth = 10;
      int borderheight = borderWidth;
      Rectangle innerRect = new Rectangle(borderWidth, borderheight, w-(borderWidth*2), h-(borderheight*2));

      // if we didn't find this image in the hashtable, we'll draw the image.
      if(bi == null){
        bi = (BufferedImage) createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2D = bi.createGraphics();

        Color shadowcolor = getBackground().darker();
        // would like to have gotten lightcolor with the brighter() method, but that
        // method doesn't always produce a color different from the original color.
        Color lightcolor = Color.white;

        //sets of polygon points
        int leftXpoints[]   = {0, borderWidth, borderWidth, 0};
        int leftYpoints[]   = {0, borderheight, h-borderheight, h};
        int topXpoints[]    = {0, w, w-borderWidth, borderWidth};
        int topYpoints[]    = {0, 0, borderheight, borderheight};
        int rightXpoints[]  = {w, w, w-borderWidth, w-borderWidth};
        int rightYpoints[]  = {0, h, h-borderheight, borderheight};
        int bottomXpoints[] = {borderWidth, w-borderWidth, w, 0};
        int bottomYpoints[] = {h-borderheight, h-borderheight, h, h};

        //define polys
        Polygon leftpoly   = new Polygon(leftXpoints,   leftYpoints,   4);
        Polygon toppoly    = new Polygon(topXpoints,    topYpoints,    4);
        Polygon rightpoly  = new Polygon(rightXpoints,  rightYpoints,  4);
        Polygon bottompoly = new Polygon(bottomXpoints, bottomYpoints, 4);

        //draw the right-hand beveled edge
        g2D.setClip(rightpoly);
        GradientPaint p = new GradientPaint(w-borderWidth, 0, getForeground(),
            w, 0, shadowcolor);
        g2D.setPaint(p);
        g2D.fillRoundRect(0, 0, w, h, arc, arc);

        //draw the bottom-hand beveled edge
        g2D.setClip(bottompoly);
        p = new GradientPaint(0, h-borderheight,
                              getForeground(), 0,
                              h, shadowcolor);
        g2D.setPaint(p);
        g2D.fillRoundRect(0, 0, w, h, arc,
                          arc);

        //draw the left-hand beveled edge
        g2D.setClip(leftpoly);
        p = new GradientPaint(0, 0,
                              lightcolor, borderWidth,
                              0, getForeground());
        g2D.setPaint(p);
        g2D.fillRoundRect(0, 0, w, h, arc,
                          arc);

        //draw the top-hand beveled edge
        g2D.setClip(toppoly);
        p = new GradientPaint(0, 0,
                              lightcolor, 0,
                              borderheight, getForeground());
        g2D.setPaint(p);
        g2D.fillRoundRect(0, 0, w, h, arc,
                          arc);

        //now draw inner rectangle
        g2D.setClip(innerRect);
        g2D.setColor(getForeground());
        g2D.fill(innerRect);

        g.drawImage(bi, null, getX(), getY());
                 m_imagetable.put("Pressed."+"SKINZ"+"."+getBackground().toString()+"."+getSize().toString(), bi);
      }
      else {
        g2D = (Graphics2D)bi.getGraphics();
      }

      g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);

      innerRect.x -=6;
      innerRect.width += 12;
      g.setClip(innerRect);

      // icons take precedence over text.
      if(getIcon()==null)
        paintText(g,innerRect.x,innerRect.y,innerRect.width,innerRect.height);
      else
        paintCenteredIcon(g, ((ImageIcon)getIcon()).getImage());
    }


    public void setButtonStyle(int style){
      switch (style) {
      case SKINZ:
      case IMAGES:
          setFont(m_originalfont);//new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 20));
          setBorder(null);
        break;
      case JAVA_LIKE:
        setBorderWidth(2);
      case JAVA_DEFAULT:
      case CLASSIC:
      case ROLLOVER:
      default:
        setBorder(m_originalborder);
        setFont(m_originalfont);
        break;
      }
      buttonStyle = style;
    }

}
```

Any suggestion to change the color by using same above code?
Thanks
Palanisamy

Answer (score 1):

- I think override `BasicButtonUI` is better and easiest of ways, majority of changes isn't Look and Feel sensitive,
- you can to decide which one of methods you want to override or stays unchanged, reason for is every methods implemented in JButton, ButtonModel, ButtonGroups API works as were implemented by Swing Team for standard (un_touched) JButton
- example for [MetalButtonUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/2853553)

Comment: I losing of supporting the HTML format when go with way. is there any way to keep HTML support in button?

Comment: by default JButton accept Html <=3.2v, with reduced support for css

Comment: I achieved the back & fore ground swipe by using below code. but the html is not supporting.


// paint foreground
         //g.setColor(foregroundColor);
          GradientPaint gradient4 = new GradientPaint(
            0.0F, (float) c.getHeight() / (float) 2, foregroundColor, 0.0F, c.getHeight(), foregroundColor);
          g2D.setPaint( gradient4 );

         String s = ((JButton)c).getText();
         x = I.left;
         y = I.top + fm.getAscent();
         g.drawString(s, x, y);
           //super.paint(g, c);