# How to give a JButton both an ImageIcon and background color?

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to do both

```
button.setBackground(Color.green.darker());
```

and

```
button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(buttonImg.getScaledInstance(15, 15, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
```

so that both the image and the background color are visible? Is there some sort of transparency setting on the button's image that I'm missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is the image I'm trying to use. As you can see, it has transparency.
http://www.clipartlord.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/bomb3.png

What I am trying to get is the image to show up on the Button with the background color of green filling in the transparency. Right now when I try to do it, if I add the image at all, the background color is not visible whatsoever. But if I don't add the image, the background color is visible. I hope this helps.

Comment: Is the image transparent?

Comment: And is the button opaque?

Comment: And is `setContentAreaFilled` set to `false`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes the image has transparency around the subject (i.e. no whitespace). What will setContentAreaFilled do?

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes the button is opaque

Comment: The area that is "painted" is always the "background", most look and feels "paint" the button shape as a separate element, so the "background" might change, but the actual "button area" won't. Maybe consider adding an image and some code to demonstrate your problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer I edited the question with that information.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be trivial because depending on the look and feel background color doesn't necessarily correspond to color of the button face. eg. With osx default look and feel the face of the button is white regardless. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751311/creating-a-custom-button-in-java-with-jbutton/5755124#5755124) is an example of creating a custom button. Do you want to change the background of *all* of your buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the LookAndFeel does not support what you want to achieve. Here is an image from the meta theme, on the left, and osx aqua theme.

[image: two different, right is osx aqua and left is metal]

If you want *all* of your JButton backgrounds to change you can try using a LookAndFeel that supports changing the UI. Unfortunately the aqua them does not let you change the default background for a button even using the `UIManager#set`

If you only want to do one button, you can change the button UI.

```
button.setUI(new BasicButtonUI());
```

That one doesn't look too nice, you can set the UI to one from another LookAndFeel,

```
button.setUI(new MotifButtonUI());
```

(Also doesn't look very nice, but now it *buttons*.)

Finally you can also create your own ButtonUI, or do some custom painting.

Comment: so the first one, the BasicButtonUI, works almost perfectly. The only issue is that, when it is placed next to other buttons, there is no border or anything to differentiate between them. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: never mind, I got it. I just created a new Border with a line border and applied that to the buttons, while using BasicButtonUI. Thanks for your help!