# show the 1st and 2nd value of object in comboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a combobox with list of authors and with change in combobox I have to show the author's detail in table using java swing. I did like:

```
for(Author author: Application.authors){
    jComboBoxAuthors.addItem(author);
}
```

and with change in item selected :

```
if(jComboBoxAuthors.getSelectedIndex()>0){
    Author author = (Author)e.getItem();
    String name = author.getFirstName()+" "+author.getLastName();
}
```

It shows object in combo but i need the name only and if I `dojComboBoxAuthors.addItem(author.getFirstName());`
 I can't get value in table ie. name return nothing. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Use a [*Custom Renderer*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10951919/230513).

Comment: I think you might like to take a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer)

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom renderer will break the default functionality of a JComboBox. That is you will no longer be able to select an item using the keyboard.

Check out [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for more information and a more complete solution that shows how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is override the toString() method as following

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName+" "+lastName; // so that name will be displayed instead of default object
    }
```

But it has its limitations. Hope it helps