# How to stop JButton background only appearing as a border

Tags: java, swing, background, jbutton

I'm creating an AbstractColorChooserPanel for recent colours (in a 4 * 4 grid) and while setting the background colour for the recent colours it only appears as a border to the button instead of filling it.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065691/how-to-set-the-background-color-of-a-jbutton-on-the-mac-os) the code below should work:

```java
button.setBackground(Color.RED);
button.setOpaque(true);
```

Ive also tried adding

```java
button.setBorderPainted(false);
```

but all that displays is a grey (standard colour) button with a red border.
I have tried putting the code on a button outside the JColorChooser and received the same effect. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OqJJ.png)

How do I make it so the entire button is filled with the red colour instead of just the border?

EDIT: The problem turned out to be the UIManager (default system look and feel)
To solve this I modified the code used in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973073/background-color-of-button-when-using-windows-laf) solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this :

```
button.setContentAreaFilled( false );
```

Comment: That just removes the buttons all together sadly, leaving only the dotted outline when you click on them.

Comment: Maybe try changing/setting the look and feel if you haven't already ?

Comment: I was on systemlookandfeel and after reverting to the java default look and feel it seems to have sorted itself, thanks.

Comment: Now just to figure out how to make it work with system look and feel