# How to display a color selector when clicking a button?

Tags: java, button, colors, shapes

I'm making a program that draws some shapes and fills them with color. I need to change the 'line' color, and want the user to be able to select the color.

How can I, when clicking a button "Choose Color", have a set
of colours appear below the button? Is it possible for the selector to be embedded in the UI below the button (and not pop up in a window)?

I want to display a color selector like in Paint.

Comment: Yea! I need that to appear when clicking a button. How can I do that, you know? Is it possible to 'not' pop up the window to choose? I mean, below the button having already that jColorChooser.

Comment: look this http://www.javatpoint.com/JColorChooser-class

Comment: @Afonso Please check my updated answer. It shows a way to include the color chooser into the contentpane, without using a popup.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a colour selection button class:

- shows current selected color
- opens a JColorChooser dialog when pressed
- fires events when a color is selected

Use it in this way:

```
ColorChooserButton colorChooser = new ColorChooserButton(Color.WHITE);
colorChooser.addColorChangedListener(new ColorChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void colorChanged(Color newColor) {
            // do something with newColor ...
    }
});
```

[image]

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JColorChooser;

    public class ColorChooserButton extends JButton {

        private Color current;

        public ColorChooserButton(Color c) {
            setSelectedColor(c); 
            addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    Color newColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Choose a color", current);
                    setSelectedColor(newColor);
                }
            });
        }

        public Color getSelectedColor() {
            return current;
        }

        public void setSelectedColor(Color newColor) {
            setSelectedColor(newColor, true);
        }

        public void setSelectedColor(Color newColor, boolean notify) {

            if (newColor == null) return;

            current = newColor;
            setIcon(createIcon(current, 16, 16));
            repaint();

            if (notify) {
                // Notify everybody that may be interested.
                for (ColorChangedListener l : listeners) {
                    l.colorChanged(newColor);
                }
            }
        }

        public static interface ColorChangedListener {
            public void colorChanged(Color newColor);
        }

        private List<ColorChangedListener> listeners = new ArrayList<ColorChangedListener>();

        public void addColorChangedListener(ColorChangedListener toAdd) {
            listeners.add(toAdd);
        }

        public static  ImageIcon createIcon(Color main, int width, int height) {
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();
            graphics.setColor(main);
            graphics.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            graphics.setXORMode(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width-1, height-1);
            image.flush();
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
            return icon;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `JColorChooser` like this:

```
Color newColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Choose a color", Color.RED);
```

- The first argument is the parent `java.awt.Component` instance. Could also be
  `null`.
- The second argument is the title for the dialog.
- The third argument is the color it should select as default.

The dialog returns the selected color if the user presses `ok` or `null` if he clicked on `cancel`.

See this page for more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html.

**Edit: include ColorChooser into existing contentpane**

The above code shows how to create a pop up with for the `JColorChooser`, but it is also possible to "include" it into the existing contentpane.

This is the code to initialize both components (`JButton` and `JColorChooser`):

```
button = new JButton("Choose color");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        toggleColorChooser(); // show and hide the color chooser
    }
});
button.setBounds(10, 11, 150, 23);
contentPane.add(button);

colorChooser = new JColorChooser(Color.BLACK); // default color is black
colorChooser.setBorder(null);
colorChooser.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        colorChanged(); // change background color of "button"
    }
});
```

The button will be added immediately, but the color chooser not yet. It will be added in the `toggleColorChooser` method:

```
protected void toggleColorChooser() {
    if (toggled) {
        contentPane.remove(colorChooser);
    } else {
        colorChooser.setBounds(button.getX(), button.getY() + 20, 600, 300);
        colorChooser.setVisible(true);
        contentPane.add(colorChooser);
    }
    toggled = !toggled;
    contentPane.validate();
    contentPane.repaint();
}
```

The color chooser will be added to the panel beneath the button. You may change the bounds if you have a different layout or if you're using a layout manager.

As you can see, you'll need a variable called `toggled`. Just add it as class variable:

```
private boolean toggled = false;
```

The last method will be called it the user selects a color on the color chooser. It will change the background color of the button:

```
protected void colorChanged() {
    button.setBackground(colorChooser.getSelectionModel().getSelectedColor());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I improved a Java Swing Color Picker component that looks beautiful and allows enhanced color manipulation:

[image]

Simply add the Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.drjekyll</groupId>
  <artifactId>colorpicker</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to your project. Now you can add the ColorPickerPanel to your user interface.

Comment: can you give a sample about usage?

Comment: Of course! You'll find one here:

https://gitlab.com/dheid/colorpicker/blob/master/src/test/java/com/bric/colorpicker/ColorPickerExample.java

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by using ColorPickerDialog dialog = new ColorPickerDialog(); in button event. I really liked this lib.