# Where do I find the icons and other resources for metal look and feel?

Tags: java, customization, jbutton, look-and-feel

I want my pressed buttons to look pressed, but I am looking to make it as easy as possible by modifying the default button from the Metal look and feel in Photoshop.
From there I could simply use the jbutton.setPressedIcon() method and tell it to use the modified button when it's pressed.
I've had no luck, I googled a bunch, search Stack Overflow a bunch, and checked the documentation for the JDK file structure at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/linux/jdkfiles.html.

I'm on a Mac OS X Lion box, but I figured the linux file structure would be similar and it is, it just doesn't reference anything related to look and feel or images in general.

Of course I tried digging around in the jdk folder using finder, and found lots of stuff there, but no images that I can edit.

Comment: I don't think the buttons are images, they are painted (by the UI).

Comment: Some code is needed to help you. To be honest, I didn't understand what is your exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this question addresses my need, I was thinking about it in the wrong way.

[repaint swing button with different gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458982/repaint-swing-button-with-different-gradient/5845007#5845007)