# How to get back the original look and feel color of a button after changing its color?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, look-and-feel, uimanager

I changed the color of my button. Now I want its original look and feel back. I want to change the color once to a color that i like. After that, I want the button to get its original look back.

How do I do that ?

Here is the code to change color -

```
JButton but = JButton("Press now to up vote"); // :)
but.setBackground(Color.orange); 
//code to remove this color and get the original look back ???
```

Comment: How did you changed color? Any code?

Comment: by default question is regullar without any code, (I'm user that required, asking for an SSCCE in all cases)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Color oldColor = myButton.getBackground();
myButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
// ... do stuff
myButton.setBackground(oldColor);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to find out the name/code of the old color  ?

Comment: You can do toString() on the Color object.  It will output the components, for example: `java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]`.  There are other options to get the components.  See the [Color API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/Color.html).

Answer (score 4):

> I want the button to get its original look back.

- this code should be only `button.setBackground(null);`

> Is there a way to find out the name/code of the old color

- by default `Colors` has not a names, only safe `Colors(blue, red, orange ....)`
- `old color` not [JButton has arrays of Colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5845007/714968)
- UIManager returns `javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=xxx, g=xxx, b=xx]`,  contains arrays of `Colors` and `Insets`